# Бесконечный запуск процессов грузящих процессор в ubuntu-server 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сервер, bash, shell

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, поле покупки VPS у хецнера, по пока непонятным мне причинам, кто то бесконечно запускает стандартные консольные команды `who`, `netstat` и другие. Это осталось бы не замеченным если не полная загрузка ими процессора.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я убиваю какой либо процесс который сильнее всех грузит

```
kill -9 13213
```

то сразу запускается `netstat` и т.д. `lsof` показывает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запуск:

```
rkhunter -c -sk
chkrootkit
```

При попытке запуска:

```
lsof -c 13213
```

Ничего не выдает.

В `/proc/{pid}/maps` видим это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`/usr/bin/uspezmpywh` - этот файл естественно постоянно меняется после убийства процесса.
В нем:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ничего существенного не нашёл. В самой системе если смотреть через `who` только один авторизованный пользователь. Изначально к системе имели доступ много разных людей поэтому могло что угодно занестись туда. С таким столкнулся первый раз. Буду благодарен за любую подсказку.

UPD: В `/proc/{pid}/status`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В `/etc/init` ничего обнаружить не удалось в `/etc/init.d/{name_proc}`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37100/discussion-on-question-by-alex10-----).

Answer (score 1):

https://habrahabr.ru/post/248933/

HEUR:Trojan-DDoS.Linux.Xarcen.a

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.